# Android :Error while creating file : ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, file

i'm trying to create a new file with this code but i have the "java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

This is my code: i hope you can help me.

```
final File f = new File(Environment.
    getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + "/"
                    + MainActivity.getContext().getPackageName() 
                    + "/wifip2pshared-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + ".jpg");
Log.d("WIFI","file created :"+f.getAbsolutePath());
File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
Log.d("WIFI","dir created :"+dirs.getAbsolutePath());
dirs.mkdirs();
f.createNewFile();
```

And I did declare the permission in the android manifest.

Comment: Have you addded the Read and Write Permissions in your manifest. ?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle run time permissions if you user Android M or next version

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "wifip2pshared/" + dirName);
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            // Do something on success
        } else {
            // Do something else on failure
        }
```

---

### OR

```
  File dir = new File("storage/emulated/0/wifip2pshared/" + dirName); 
try { 
      if (!dir.exists()) { 
          if (dir.mkdir()) { 
              System.out.println("Directory created"); 
           } else { 
              System.out.println("Directory is not created"); 
           } 
     } 
 } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
 }
```

Comment: OR
            File dir = new File("storage/emulated/0/wifip2pshared/" + dirName);
               try {
                  if (!dir.exists()) {
                    if (dir.mkdir()) {
                        System.out.println("Directory created");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Directory is not created");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your manifest application

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```